# pass multiple models data from controller to view MVC C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have three models,

- Student(Id, name, Dept, registration_number, session)
- Result(Id, registration_number, semester, cgpa)
- Payment(Id, registration_number, amount, date)

I don't want to create any other model. In a view, I want to show all data of a student with result and payment details. How can I pass these data to a view.

Comment: How are the Student and Result/Payment connected ?

Comment: Those are connected by "registration_number"